# Fix missing parts of humanoid

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

My model is a sitting humanoid. You can see a **video** here, which shows the problem perfectly:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FcmjXTwH0bRUUeM3XCI1i6FRBi-wFu-3

The model is to be used as an enemy in a unity game. Those parts should be fixed in such a way you would expect it to look like if the missing parts were there.

Your brain already completes it, this is what the model should look like. I created an example outline on the right upper arm of the creature.

Example: arms are round. You only see parts of the arms, sometimes more, sometimes less. In an abstract way, arms are cylinders. So there should be cylinders as a rough guide along the fragments. As I wrote, your brain knows it already what it should look like.

My question also adresses the painting of the non-existing parts to make them match.

How do I fix the missing parts efficiently the way described, so it looks like a sitting humanoid?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Could you please add some info about the final usage of the model? What kind of mesh are you expecting? And how you imagine those parts should be fixed?

Comment: Please add images as part of your question.

Comment: @cegaton You have all the data to answer the question. I made enough effort, now it is your turn.